# How to add index in Database using ELKI java API for Custom POJO with String type fields

Tags: cluster-analysis, java, dbscan, elki

I am using DBSCAN to cluster some categorical data using a POJO. My class looks like this

```
public class Dimension {
    private String app;
    private String node;
    private String cluster;
 .............
```

All my fields are String instead of integer or Float because they are discrete/categorical value. Rest of my code is as follows.

```
    final SimpleTypeInformation<Dimension> dimensionTypeInformation = new SimpleTypeInformation<>(Dimension.class);
    PrimitiveDistanceFunction<Dimension> dimensionPrimitiveDistanceFunction = new PrimitiveDistanceFunction<Dimension>() {
        public double distance(Dimension d1, Dimension d2) {
            return simpleMatchingCoefficient(d1, d2);
        }
        public SimpleTypeInformation<? super Dimension> getInputTypeRestriction() {
            return dimensionTypeInformation;
        }
        public boolean isSymmetric() {
            return true;
        }
        public boolean isMetric() {
            return true;
        }
        public <T extends Dimension> DistanceQuery<T> instantiate(Relation<T> relation) {
            return new PrimitiveDistanceQuery<>(relation, this);
        }
    };
    DatabaseConnection dbc = new DimensionDatabaseConnection(dimensionList);
    Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
    db.initialize();
    DBSCAN<Dimension> dbscan = new DBSCAN<>(dimensionPrimitiveDistanceFunction, 0.6, 20);
    Result result = dbscan.run(db);
```

Now as expected this code works fine for small dataset but gets very very slow when my dataset gets bigger. So I want to add an index to speed up the process. But all the index that I could think of require me to implement NumberVector. But my class has only Strings not number. 
What index can I use in this case ? can I use the distance function, double simpleMatchingCoefficient(Dimension d1, Dimension d2) to create an IndexFactory ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) three broad families of indexes:

1. Coordinate based indexes, such as the k-d-tree and R-tree. These work well on dense, continuous variables
2. Metric indexes, that require the distance function to satisfy the triangle inequality. These can work on any kind of data, but may still need a fairly smooth distribution of distance values (e.g., they will not help with the discrete metric, that is 0 of x=y and 1 otherwise).
3. Inverted lookup indexes. They are mostly used for text search, and exploit that for each attribute only a small subset of the data is relevant. These work well for high-cardinality discrete attributes.

In your case, I'd consider an inverted index. If you have a lot of attributes, a metric index may work, but I doubt that holds, because you use POJOs with strings to store your data.

And of course, profile your code and check if you can improve the implementation of your distance function! E.g. string interning may help, it can reduce matching time of strings to equality testing rather than comparing each character...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The insight you provided makes sense. But unfortunately all the implementations of invertedIndex or any other index in ELKI seems to require that my POJO (Dimension class) implements NumberVector. I am trying to find a way around that.

Comment: One of the features of ELKI usually is that it has support for all these types. But an index of type 1 indeed *should* require number vectors. Don't use type 1!

Comment: Even Type 3 (Inverted index) de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.invertedlist.InMemoryInvertedIndex requires the class to extend NumberVector.

Comment: These tend to be extremely specific to your data type. I wasn't aware there even was a way to use these with number vectors. But you *will* need to implement these for exactly your POJO (and distance!)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the SMC is usually defined as a *similarity* function, not a *distance* function, but 1-SMC is the usual transformation. Just don't confuse these two.

For the simple matching coefficient, you probably will want to **build your own inverted index**, for your particular POJO data type. Because of your POJO design (`Dimension` sounds like a very bad name, btw.), this cannot be implemented in a *generic*, reusable, way easily. That would require expensive introspection, and still require customization: should string matches be case sensitive? Do they need trimming? Should they be tokenized?

Your inverted index will then likely contain a series of maps specific to your POJO:

```
Map<String, DBIDs> by_app;
Map<String, DBIDs> by_node;
Map<String, DBIDs> by_cluster;
...
```

and for each attribute, you get the matching DBIDs, and count how often they appear. The most often returned `DBIDs` have the highest SMC (and hence lowest distance).
At some point, you can forget counting candidates that can no longer make it into the result set. Just look up an *information retrieval book* how such search works.

Such an index is beneficial if the average number of matches for each attribute is low. You can further speed this up by bitmap index compression and such techniques, but that is likely not necessary to do (at some point, it can be attractive to build upon existing tools such as Apache Lucene to handle the search then).